# Analyzing UPnP entries from home router

Tags: network, port-forwarding

I'm using a tplink router for my home LAN and just noticed that in the UPnP section in its control panel there are two entries with `App description: Teredo of tipe: UDP and ports: 55566 and 49868`

How can I analyze what application is using those forwarding? Does it seem suspicious?
(There is no `remove` button in the web interface of the router so I cannot just remove those entries...)

Comment: Why downvote? Seems like a valid question that others might run into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of [UPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UPnP) is that devices within the network can discover and connect to each other without further configuration by the end-user. That's why UPnP connections are registered by your router, but aren't editable. The only option you have (with your router) is to disable or enable UPnP entirely.

The description of the application **might** refer to the [Teredo tunneling protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teredo_tunneling), wich is used to enable [ipv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) communication within a [ipv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) network. It is suspicious that the ports you mention aren't de default Teredo ports ([3544](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4380)). You might want to check with devices within your network if they have ipv6/Teredo enabled, or if your [ISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider) is providing ipv6 services through Teredo tunneling. As long as your ISP doesn't *require* ipv6 (most of them don't), then it is safe (and maybe even safer) to disable any ipv6 services within your network.

It is generally regarded a bad practice to leave UPnP open towards the internet, because it can be used to [gain access to your internal network](http://www.howtogeek.com/122487/htg-explains-is-upnp-a-security-risk/). You can test if UPnP is exposed to the internet with [this](https://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?bh0bkyd2) site.

Consider if you have any devices or applications that need UPnP or if you can do without it.